# R pipelines: execute simultaneously

Tags: r, dataframe, pipeline

I have code in pipeline format to transform a dataframe and I'm stuck with calculating mean and SE. I can only do one of them because the functions are executed in sequence (of course). I need a way to do it simultaneously (or at least let them both work on the same intermediate object).

**Situation**

I have 6 different treatments, with 4 replicates each, and x = counts of a bug in 3 different lifestages.

The raw data are organized in a way that the counts of each lifestage is a different variable. I reorder this in a dataframe with a variable "count" and a variable "lifestage" in order to make plots with `ggplot2`.

Before I reorder the variables, I calculate the mean of the 4 replicates for each treatment at each timestep. Now I also need the SE, but this part doesn't work. If I only calculate the SE, it works. But because I FIRST calculate the mean, the information of the 4 replicates is gone and I can't calc the SE anymore.

I know this is of course the whole idea of a pipeline, doing things in sequence. But is there anyway to make 2 things go simultaneously or on the same intermediate output from the previous step? Or is it impossible and do I have to use a whole different approach in order to get both mean and SE?

**Code**

```
# example data
Object <- c(rep("A",10),rep("B",10),rep("C",10),
            rep("D",10),rep("E",10),rep("F",10))
Repl <- as.factor(c(rep(1,60),rep(2,60),rep(3,60),rep(4,60)))
Days <- rep(c(0,7,14,21,28,35,42,49,56,63),24)
N1.N3 <- sample(1:10,size=240,replace=T)
N4.N5 <- sample(1:10,size=240,replace=T)
Adult <- sample(1:10,size=240,replace=T)
dfBugs <- data.frame(Object,Repl,Days,N1.N3,N4.N5,Adult)


# calculate mean & SE of Macro counts per object and per date
Bugs <- dfBugs %>%
  group_by(Object, Days) %>%
  summarise(
    count = n(),
    N1.N3 = mean(N1.N3, na.rm = TRUE),
    N4.N5 = mean(N4.N5, na.rm = TRUE),
    Adult = mean(Adult, na.rm = TRUE),
    N1.SE = sd(N1.N3, na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(count),
    N4.SE = sd(N4.N5, na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(count),
    Ad.SE = sd(Adult, na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(count)
  )

# put counts of different life stages in 1 column
Bugs <- Bugs %>%
gather(Stage,Counts,-Days,-Object,-count)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is as you said that the information about the stage is gone after you calculate the mean. This is because you overwrite the original column with the mean (i.e. give the same name).
You can solve this by, first calculating the SE and then the mean or name the mean differently.

**Different order:**

```
dfBugs %>% 
  group_by(Object, Days) %>%
  summarise(
    count = n(),
    N1.SE = sd(N1.N3, na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(count),
    N4.SE = sd(N4.N5, na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(count),
    Ad.SE = sd(Adult, na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(count), 
    N1.N3 = mean(N1.N3, na.rm = TRUE),
    N4.N5 = mean(N4.N5, na.rm = TRUE),
    Adult = mean(Adult, na.rm = TRUE))

# A tibble: 60 x 9
# Groups:   Object [?]
#    Object  Days count N1.SE N4.SE Ad.SE N1.N3 N4.N5 Adult
#    <fct>  <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1 A          0     4 2.10  0.707 1.55   5.5   8     5.75
#  2 A          7     4 1.03  1.97  1.89   7.25  5.75  4.5 
#  3 A         14     4 1.31  1.94  0.957  3.25  6.5   7.5 
#  4 A         21     4 1.32  0.629 0.866  5.5   2.25  5.5 
#  5 A         28     4 1.29  1.55  1.89   5     5.5   6.25
#  6 A         35     4 1.55  1.44  1.03   6.5   6.75  4.25
#  7 A         42     4 1.31  1.49  0.707  5.25  5.25  7   
#  8 A         49     4 0.866 1.63  1.25   3.5   5     6.25
#  9 A         56     4 1.29  1.44  1.03   4     6.5   6.25
# 10 A         63     4 1.47  1.19  1.60   7     3.5   3.25
# ... with 50 more rows
```

**Different name:**

```
dfBugs %>% 
  group_by(Object, Days) %>%
  summarise(
    count = n(), 
    N1.N3.mean = mean(N1.N3, na.rm = TRUE),
    N4.N5.mean = mean(N4.N5, na.rm = TRUE),
    Adult.mean = mean(Adult, na.rm = TRUE),
    N1.SE = sd(N1.N3, na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(count),
    N4.SE = sd(N4.N5, na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(count),
    Ad.SE = sd(Adult, na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(count))

# A tibble: 60 x 9
# Groups:   Object [?]
#    Object  Days count N1.N3.mean N4.N5.mean Adult.mean N1.SE N4.SE Ad.SE
#    <fct>  <dbl> <int>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1 A          0     4       5.5        8          5.75 2.10  0.707 1.55 
#  2 A          7     4       7.25       5.75       4.5  1.03  1.97  1.89 
#  3 A         14     4       3.25       6.5        7.5  1.31  1.94  0.957
#  4 A         21     4       5.5        2.25       5.5  1.32  0.629 0.866
#  5 A         28     4       5          5.5        6.25 1.29  1.55  1.89 
#  6 A         35     4       6.5        6.75       4.25 1.55  1.44  1.03 
#  7 A         42     4       5.25       5.25       7    1.31  1.49  0.707
#  8 A         49     4       3.5        5          6.25 0.866 1.63  1.25 
#  9 A         56     4       4          6.5        6.25 1.29  1.44  1.03 
# 10 A         63     4       7          3.5        3.25 1.47  1.19  1.60 
# ... with 50 more rows
```

As you want to transform the data anyway into long format another approach could be to first transform them and then calculate mean and SE:

```
dfBugs %>% 
  gather(Stage, Counts, N1.N3, N4.N5, Adult) %>% 
  group_by(Object, Days, Stage) %>% 
  summarise(count = n(), 
            Mean = mean(Counts), 
            SE = sd(Counts, na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(count)) 

# A tibble: 180 x 6
# Groups:   Object, Days [?]
#    Object  Days Stage count  Mean    SE
#    <fct>  <dbl> <chr> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1 A          0 Adult     4  5.75 1.55 
#  2 A          0 N1.N3     4  5.5  2.10 
#  3 A          0 N4.N5     4  8    0.707
#  4 A          7 Adult     4  4.5  1.89 
#  5 A          7 N1.N3     4  7.25 1.03 
#  6 A          7 N4.N5     4  5.75 1.97 
#  7 A         14 Adult     4  7.5  0.957
#  8 A         14 N1.N3     4  3.25 1.31 
#  9 A         14 N4.N5     4  6.5  1.94 
# 10 A         21 Adult     4  5.5  0.866
# ... with 170 more rows
```

Comment: Brilliant! thanks for explaining the different solutions!

Answer (score 3):

We can use `summarise_at` and specify the functions to execute within `funs`

```
dfBugs %>% 
   group_by(Object, Days) %>% 
   summarise_at(vars(N1.N3:Adult), funs(mean = mean(., na.rm = TRUE), 
     SE = sd(., na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(n())))
```